# How to rewrite AST dynamically in resharper plugin?

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-plugins

The request:

I'd like to be able to write an analyzer that can provide a proxy value for a certain expression and trigger a re-parsing of the document.

The motivation:

Our code is littered with ABTests that can be either in a deployed or active state with a control and variant group. 
Determining a test's state is done through a database lookup.
For the tests that are deployed with the control group, any statement of the following form will evaluate to false:

```
if(ExperimentService.IsInVariant(ABTest.Test1))
{
}
```

I'm trying to provide tooling to make this easier to deal with at develop time by greying it out in this scenario. 
As it is, this is fairly limited and not robust because I basically have to play parser myself.

What if the actual code is

```
if(!ExperimentService.IsInVariant(ABTest.Test1))
```

or

```
if(ExperimentService.IsInVariant(ABTest.Test1) || true)
```

or

```
var val = ..... && (ExperimentService.IsInVariant(ABTest.Test1);
if(val){
  // val is always going to be false if we deployed control.
}
```

A possible approach I could see provided is by allowing us to write analyzers that are fired once and rewrite the tree before the actual IDE parsing happens (or, well, just parse it a second time).
These should only fire once and allow us to replace a certain expression with another. This would allow me to swap all of these experiment calls for true and false literals.

As a result, these sections could benefit from all the other IDE features such as code greying for unreachable code but also more intricate ones like a variable that will never have a different value

Obviously this is just an example and I'm not sure how feasible it is. Any suggestions for a proper feature or something that already exists are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an approach that doesn't have a compromise.

ReSharper doesn't support rewriting the AST before analysis - that would just rewrite the text in the file.

You could write an analyser that greys out the code, by applying a "dead code" highlight to the contents of the `if` block, but as you say, you'd need to parse the code and analyse control flow in order to get it correct, and I think that would be very difficult (ReSharper does provide a control flow graph, so you could walk it, but it would be up to you to *A.* find the return value of `IsInVariant` and *B.* trace that value through whatever conditions, `&&` or `||` statements until you find an appropriate `if` block).

Alternatively, you could mark the `IsInVariant` method with the `ContractAnnotation` attribute, something like:

```cs
[ContractAnnotation("=> false")]
public bool IsInVariant(string identifier)
{
  // whatever...
}
```

This will tell ReSharper's analysis that this method *always* returns `false` (you can also say it will return `true`/`false`/`null`/not null based on specific input). Because it always returns `false`, ReSharper will grey out the code in the `if` statement, or the `else` branch if you do `if (!IsInVariant(…))`.

The downside here is that ReSharper will also add a warning to the `if` statement to tell you that the expression always returns `false`. So, it's a compromise, but you could change the severity of that warning to Hint, so it's not so intrusive.

Comment: I hear ya, my last idea would be this (if you can spot anything that sounds wrong?). What if I create my own C# language service that overrides the resharper's CsharpService implementation? I would decorate the existing resharper service with my own, and I can wrap the CSharpParser with my own parser, and potentially take care of the final parsing of AST?

Comment: I'd say the very best of luck :) I have no idea what would actually happen, but I'd be surprised if it works. ReSharper keeps the AST and the text of the document in sync - if you change one, the other changes. If you make one side different, I doubt it would end well. I suspect writing an analyser that used the control flow graph would be easier (but still non-trivial) and more likely to work. But hey, half the fun is in trying :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not enough to really warrant the bounty, but one solution that might apply from the [developer documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/README.html) is to create a [custom language](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/CustomLanguages/Registration.html) and extend the basic rules.

You said

> I'm trying to provide tooling to make this easier to deal with at develop time by greying it out in this scenario.

Greying out the corresponding parts might just be done by altering syntax highlighting rules.

See [this example for `.tt` files.](https://github.com/MrJul/ForTea/tree/master/GammaJul.ReSharper.ForTea)